# Clearcase Sync Issue

Tags: version-control, clearcase

I've a vob, please find my vob detail

```
/usr/atria/bin/cleartool desc vob:/vobs/esam/configspecs
versioned object base "/vobs/esam/configspecs"
  created 2004-02-16T19:20:26+05:30 by van aken (cm.we2@bt0pjb)
  "ESAM build vob"
  master replica: ANTWERP_3@/vobs/esam/configspecs
  replica name: CHENNAI_1
  VOB family feature level: 4
  VOB storage host:pathname "andd006:/net/in0oianas002/in0oianas002_SAS_U1/C-T3-P-fad-vobs08/configspecs.vbs"
  VOB storage global pathname "/net/in0oianas002/in0oianas002_SAS_U1/C-T3-P-fad-vobs08/configspecs.vbs"
  database schema version: 54
  modification by remote privileged user: allowed
  atomic checkin: disabled
  VOB ownership:
    owner nobody
    group nobody
  Attributes:
    FeatureLevel = 4
  Hyperlinks:
    AdminVOB -> vob:/vobs/admin/cc_admin
```

It has two sites on site when I run lsepoch I got output as below

```
Oplog IDs for row "ANTWERP_3" (@ beantsu0090.be.alcatel-lucent.com):
 oid:12332a88.608811d8.8c2c.00:01:80:80:57:94=156342      (ANTWERP_3)
 oid:45a89286.940111da.81f9.00:01:83:b0:4c:43=24203       (CHENNAI_1)

Oplog IDs for row "CHENNAI_1" (@ andd006.in.alcatel-lucent.com):
 oid:12332a88.608811d8.8c2c.00:01:80:80:57:94=156342      (ANTWERP_3)
 oid:45a89286.940111da.81f9.00:01:83:b0:4c:43=24203       (CHENNAI_1)
```

On other site it has

```
 Oplog IDs for row "ANTWERP_3" (@ beantsu0090.be.alcatel-lucent.com):
 oid:12332a88.608811d8.8c2c.00:01:80:80:57:94=156346      (ANTWERP_3)
 oid:45a89286.940111da.81f9.00:01:83:b0:4c:43=24203       (CHENNAI_1)

 Oplog IDs for row "ANTWERP_3" (@ beantsu0090.be.alcatel-lucent.com):
 oid:12332a88.608811d8.8c2c.00:01:80:80:57:94=156346      (ANTWERP_3)
 oid:45a89286.940111da.81f9.00:01:83:b0:4c:43=24203       (CHENNAI_1)
```

But when I run the syncreplica command on both sites it shows as Target replica(s) up to date

```
/usr/atria/bin/multitool syncreplica -export -fship CHENNAI_1@/vobs/esam/configspecs
```

Could you please help on this case, somewhere I'm missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find two avenues to pursue in "[Different epoch values](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26629942/6309)":

- either on the target side (if you have access), import any pending sync packet (`multitool syncreplica -import -receive`)
- or (my solution) re-exporting the all vob: `multitool mkreplica -export -maxsize 200m -nc...` and importing it

Check also the technote "[Replicated VOB cannot import or export packets from scheduled jobs](https://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21452483)"

```
ERROR: command './bin/multitool syncreplica -export  -fship    replica:<replica-name>@/<vob-tag> >&2' encountered error.
Target replica(s) up to date. No export stream generated.
```

In that technote, the cause was Cause a duplicate replica created on the same host.

> ### Diagnosing the problem
>
> On the host, run a `multitool lsreplica -l` command while inside a view and VOB context. By examining the output, you should see there is more than one replica on the same host which is invalid.
>
> ### Resolving the problem
>
> Contact IBM Rational Client Support for assistance in resolving this issue providing the following information:
>
> - Output of a `cleartool describe -l vob:<vob-tag>` on in the "good" VOB to obtain the actual replica name.
> - Output of a `multitool lsreplica -l` to get the replica name of the duplicate replica on that host. This will also identify the mastering replica.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to guess that "the other site" is ANTWERP_3. If it's not, someone messed up on restoring a replica from backup, and you likely have bigger potential problems than "not syncing". (Cut and paste error in the results there, BTW)

At beantsu0090.be.alcatel-lucent.com, try to see if you can run multitool lsepoch -actual CHENNAI_1@/vobs/esam/configspecs You should see the CHENNAI_1 row from the first site. If so, run multitool chepoch -actual CHENNAI_1@/vobs/esam/configspecs and export again. You should export (with -fship) the 4 or so changes. Once you get a message back from multitool telling you it has successfully forwarded then run a multitool syncreplica -import -receive at andd006.in.alcatel-lucent.com.

Notes:

1. you generally want to redact VOB tags and hostnames.
2. The VOB describe is done from a host that cannot determine the VOB owner or primary group, if this is done from the VOB server host, you need to resolve this as it could prevent updates from applying.

If this is not an identity preserving replica, I would recommend resetting the VOB owner and primary group (cleartool protectvob -chown ... -chgrp ... /net/in0oianas002/in0oianas002_SAS_U1/C-T3-P-fad-vobs08/configspecs.vbs) and then using vob-sidwalk -unknown -execute ... to reprotect "nobody" objects) If this is an identity preserving replica, verify the other sites before doing it to know if the other sites have different user ID repositories.